# Models for Long-Term Time-Series Forecasting and Pattern Recognition

Tags: neural-network, time-series, lstm, rnn, evolutionary-algorithms

I'm trying to find a solution for long-term electricity hourly prices forecasting. Explaining simply, I have some data from 2018 - 2021 containing Demand, Renewable Generation, Hydropower Generation, System Losses, Energy Exchange, and Electricity Prices for each Energy Submarket (all this in hourly format). What I want to answer is: is possible to create a model to predict the prices for long-term or mid-term forecasting that identify the correlation on the Data?

**For example, if I increase the Renewable Generation over the next ten years and maintain the other input variables as it is, what's the electricity hourly price?**

Is there any model that can identify, learn, and understand the data pattern and achieve this prediction? I had looked into LSTM and RNNs but sounds like that they are used in short-term forecasting.

Comment: as stated this is a broad question. You do not ask for simple time series forecasting (eg see ARIMA, LSTM, ..) but also analysis of how each variable affects mid- and long-term prices. This is quite difficult

Comment: Hi @NikosM. , thx for the answer! You are right, is quite broad but it's because I'm just searching out the possible options that I have (maybe someone used something similar but for another application)

Comment: Maybe polynomial regression modeling (which is a special case of non-linear regression) can achieve both objectives of forecasting and importance analysis of various variables in mid- and long-term